# Get row count of table while inserting data in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, count

Here is Sample Data and Schemas

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer]( [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [Name] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL, [IsDelete] [bit] NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( [Id] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Invoice]([Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,[CustomerId] [int] NOT NULL, [Amount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Invoice] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( [Id] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Insert Into Customer (Name)
Values
('Jhon'),('-Jack'),('Mary'),('-Sam');

Insert into Invoice (CustomerId,Amount)
Values (1, 22.00),(1, 34.50),(2,20.67),(2,34.67),(3,45.89),(3,20.00),(4,30.00),(4,20.00)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Customer_IsDelete]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsDelete]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Invoice]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Invoice_Invoice] FOREIGN KEY([CustomerId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Invoice] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Invoice_Invoice]
GO
```

I have following SQL Query

```
DECLARE @invoiceTable TABLE (
Id INT NOT NULL,
CustName NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
FilteredRecords INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
)

Insert into @invoiceTable(
Id,
CustName,
FilteredRecords -- ****Here I need help****
)
Select 
I.Id,
R.Name,
(Select Count(Id) from @invoiceTable)
from Invoice I Inner Join Customer R on I.CustomerId = R.Id
UPDATE @invoiceTable SET CustName= 'Anonymous' WHERE CustName Like'%-%'
Select * from @invoiceTable
where Id In (1,4)
```

Now I am getting following Obvious result.

```
Id       CustName   FilteredCount  
-------- ---------- ----------------
1        John       0
4        Anonymous  0
```

But Instead of it I want the Total Rows of @invoiceTable in FilteredCount Column.

The Expected Result is

```
Id       CustName   FilteredCount  
-------- ---------- ----------------
1        John       2
4        Anonymous  2
```

As I have only two rows in @invoiceTable I want `2` in the FilteredCount Column

Is there any way to achieve this, Help me with this.

Comment: what is the logic for `FilteredCount` ? You only count for `Id  = 1 or 4` ?

Comment: @Squirrel Yes I want count after where statement is executed, so yes in this case I am getting two records so count should be two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in `Id` `1` and `4`, you can filter it in the `INSERT` query

As for the `Anonymous`, you can use a `case` statement to do it

window function `count(*) over()` will gives you total rows in the query result

```
Insert into @invoiceTable ( Id, CustName, FilteredRecords )
Select  Id = I.Id,
        CustName = CASE WHEN R.Name Like '%-%' then 'Anonymous' else R.Name end,
        FilteredRecords = count(*) over()
from   Invoice I 
       Inner Join Customer R on I.CustomerId = R.Id
where  I.Id In (1,4)
```

Comment: In this Solution I got ```8``` as FilteredRecords, but as Result has shows two records so FilteredRecords should be ```2```, is there a way ?

Comment: Did you include the `WHERE` clause ?

Comment: Yes updated ```Id``` with ```I.Id``` as you suggested and it worked, thanks.

Comment: Is there any way that I can apply where clause on ```Id``` instead of ```I.Id``` ?

Comment: what is the different ? `I.Id` is `Id` It is the same

Comment: Yes, let's replace ```Where``` Clause with  ```Select * from @invoiceTable Where CustName Like  '%Ano%'``` in this case my Filter Count Should be ```4``` but it gives me ```8``` how can I achieve this ?

Comment: That's because you are applying the `WHERE` clause on `@invoiceTable`. It should be on the `Invoice JOIN Customer` query. When you remove the `WHERE` from the original query, you are inserting `8` rows into `@InvoiceTable`, so `FilteredRecords` gives you `8`

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if you want the count of the whole table or only the final `select`, I've gone for the latter.

You don't actually need a temporary table here at all:

```sql
Select 
    I.Id,
    Name = CASE WHEN CustName Like '%-%' THEN 'Anonymous' ELSE R.Name END,
    FilteredRecords = Count(*) over ()
from Invoice I
Inner Join Customer R on I.CustomerId = R.Id
where Id In (1,4);
```

Comment: I want count of only final select.

Comment: That's what you got!